# backgrounding a threaded application with fork()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, fork

So I have an application which uses threads. Now when the program first starts up, I want it to go through setting up database connections and whatnot before it backgrounds itself so that whatever/whoever starts the program can know if there was an error starting up.

I did some looking around and have found some resources that say 'do not mix fork and threads', while others say that forking in linux will only duplicate the main thread and leave the others alone.
In the case of the latter (where it just duplicates the main thread), how then do the threads access file level (global) variables? Will the threads not be able to access the variables that are now in the forked process's address space?

Ultimately the goal is to have the application background itself after threads have been created. If this is not possible, I can put the fork before the thread creation, just would like to do it as late as possible.

Note: at the time of the fork, the threads will be doing a sleep() loop until the main thread puts data into a shared variable for them to process. So if the sleep gets interrupted, they wont be harmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to duplicate threads as part of the `fork`, and the parent's threads will all terminate when the parent exits, so even if they could access the child's memory, it wouldn't help you. You need to either create your threads after forking, or use `pthread_atfork` to register handlers that will recreate them in the child process. I would recommend just waiting until after forking to create your threads since it's a lot simpler and more efficient.

Why is it that you want to delay forking as long as possible? If you want to maintain connection to a terminal or something until initialization is finished, you can just have the parent process wait to terminate until the child process (with its threads) is done initializing and ready to be "in the background". Various synchronization tools could be used to accomplish this. One simple one would be opening a pipe through which the child sends its output back to the parent to display; the parent could simply exit when it receives EOF on this pipe.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid for not thinking of the 'fork first, then just wait until the child has initialized before exiting' solution. Its a very clean and effective solution. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Forking a process creates two different processes and threads in one process will not be able to access memory in the second process. If you want different processes to access the same memory, you want something called shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

When a thread in a process calls `fork()`, a new process is created by copying, among other things, (1) the full address space of the process and (2) the (one) thread that called `fork`.  If there are other threads in the process, they don't get copied.  This will almost certainly lead to bugs in your program.  Hence the advice not to mix threads and forks.

If you want to create a background process with many threads, you **must** fork it before spawning any other thread.  Then, the two processes behave normally, like any two isolated processes:  threads within one process share the same memory, but your background threads and your foreground process won't share any memory (by default).

Comment: Makes sense. I was thinking maybe the different advice was due to different thread implementations. With the fork only duplicating the main thread, and the other threads not being duplicated, them not being able to access the fork's memory is how I would expect things to operate. Just didnt know if there was some background magic going on in there.